# One database per client or all clients in one database?

Tags: .net, sql-server, multi-tenant

I have to design a database structure in SQL Server for my project, being a Management Information System.

I have one master database, and whenever a new organization subscribes to our web-based application, my system creates a  new copy of the master database for that client. As time goes by the number of clients increases, so the amount of client database also increases.

Is this good a approach I am using, or do I have to use one single database for all clients?

Comment: why are you changing my question, when you don't understand my question.

Comment: I do understand your question and have edited my answer. Your initial "when ever a new client comes" was unclear.

Comment: This is a **horribly bad** approach - SQL Server can **easily** handle a "master" table with 30 companies inside it - there's absolutely **NO NEED** (and no benefit) to create a separate database for each customer....

Comment: if i don't use this approach a single table of master table will have a lot of data & of different companies. so what about performance.

Comment: The magic in SQL Server is called **proper indexing** to handle the performance - pick a **good** clustered index, and as many nonclustered indices as are really needed. Performance tune your queries, don't do any stupid and sloppy SQL programming - and performance will be just fine

Answer (score 1):

No, creating one database per client, assuming a client is just an entity in your database as opposed to a separate user of a multi-tenant application, is not a good idea.

If you want to register other entities, like hardware, projects or other resources under a client, then you store either in a separate table and create a foreign key from the resource to the client, indicating a "has-a" relation.

That would look like this:

**Clients**:

```
Id Name
1  Foo
2  Bar
```

**Resources**:

```
Id ClientId Name 
1  1        Resource of Foo
2  1        Resource of Foo
3  2        Resource of Bar
```

You could also take the above approach with a multi-tenancy system, where all users of your application run on the same database and application.

With that approach you'll have different concerns though. For example the single database might grow out of proportions, harming performance and ease of backup and restore. You'll have to add checks throughout the application that any database access occurs to rows the current user has permissions to. Rolling back an action of one user may be harder, as well as introducing new features for specific users (since they all run on the same software and database schema).

Read more about the term "multitenancy", which is what you're looking for:

- [Wikipedia: Multitenancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy)
- [MSDN: Multi-Tenant Data Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx)
- [Multi-tenancy: Individual database per tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369077/multi-tenancy-individual-database-per-tenant)
- [ASP.NET Multi tenant application with tenant specific roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246591/asp-net-multi-tenant-application-with-tenant-specific-roles)

Answering *how* to implement multitenancy would be too broad, see for example the MSDN blog series about it in the links above. As for the performance question: only you know. It all depends on your code, your data, your schema, your hardware and so on. Benchmark it.

Comment: i have one master database , when ever an organization subscribe our application(web base) we create a separate database for that organization to store their data & that separate database is a copy of Master database. if 30 companies or organization are using our system so we will have 30 client database in our server.

Comment: @TheComputerScientist and when you have 30,000 clients, you'll have 30,000 databases. When you release a major change to your system that requires database schema changes, how long will it take to roll that schema change out to all 30K databases? Or even 30 databases? How about migrating to a new SQL Server instance (upgrades, etc.)? You're going to face some very challenging scaling problems.